# How can i get current user and does user follow my page or not

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have added like button on my website but i want to check on page load that whether logged in customer already liked my fb page or not?

or is there any way to get element of like button iframe.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Like gating is not allowed. You are not allowed to show different content just because the user logged in

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, go to your page and find share/embedded link of your page. Fb will generate a link that you can paste on your website or blog. It will show direct like button and link to your page in a 300 by 300 sized box.